# Converting only the time to datetime object in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have temperature sensor data with time and date in separate columns. Since the data is for 3 hours, the date doesn't really matter. So I tried to just convert the time strings to date time objects but the year is automatically added to the converted object. I have also tried using the format string only for the time but the year is still added. Is there a way to convert only the time and leave the year out?

[Sensor Data Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdU7R.jpg)

Comment: nope, not that I know of. you could use a datetime.time object but that would mean you won't have available any of the datetime functionality pandas offerst.

Comment: Why don't you combine the date and time columns into 1 column, then you can use `pd.to_datetime` for that column.

Comment: I have tried that but it also adds the year. How would that solve the problem?

Comment: Once the time is converted to datetime format you can then just extract the hour or minute.  What is it you want to do with the hour:min data?

Comment: I want to plot the temperature data against time. I suspect if I extract the hr:min data then it wouldn't remain the timedata object. I didn't want to use the year as they clutter the axis. Since the data is for 6 hours for the same day it would be fine to do away with it.